# Are the positive rationals well ordered by this operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

The question is: "is $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ well ordered by the following operator?"

Operator '$($': Write inputs as fractions in lowest terms, $a=\frac{p_a}{q_a}, b=\frac{p_b}{q_b}$. Then, $a(b\iff p_aq_b<p_bq_a$.

I have been told by peers that no, $($ does not well-order the rationals. Still, I cannot figure out why not. My guess is that the operator, $($, does not respect transitivity. IE. if $a(b$ and $b(c$, then it is not necessarily true that $a(c$. However, I have yet to find an example of this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your $a(b$ is just $a\lt b$; if $\frac{p_a}{q_a}\lt\frac{p_b}{q_b}$ then multiply both sides by $q_aq_b$ to get $p_aq_b\lt p_bq_a$.  Likewise, you can divide $p_aq_b\lt p_bq_a$ by $q_aq_b$ to get $\frac{p_a}{q_a}\lt\frac{p_b}{q_b}$.  Do you understand why $\lt$ isn't a well-ordering on the rationals?

Comment: I do understand that < does not well-order the rationals since the rationals are dense in R. Can you elaborate on how that explains that '(' does not well-order them? @StevenStadnicki, thank you for your help so far.

Comment: If you understand that $\lt$ does not well order the rationals, you should understand that $($ does not either.  Steven Stadnicki showed that they are the same order, so if one is not a well order, neither is the other.  Your effort to find a failure of transitivity will fail for the same reason.  $)$ is transitive because $\lt$ is.

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of using a single paren as a binary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-order  is a linear order $<^*$ on  a set $S$ such that every non-empty $T\subset S$ has a $<^*$-least member.

$a(b\iff p_aq_b<p_bq_a\iff p_a/q_a<p_b/q_b\iff a<b.$ But the usual order $<$ on $Q^+$ is not a well-order. E.g. $\{1/n: n\in N\}$ has no $<$-least member.

BTW it is preferable to not use $($ as a relation-symbol. If used in an expression involving brackets, it may be hard to read. Common options include $aRb$ and $a<^*b.$

Comment: I like \prec which gives $\prec$ for an arbitrary comparison operator.